# Where pulled images of docker are stored in Windows?

Tags: docker

Although `docker info` in windows display *Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker*, but there is no such folder */var/lib/docker *. Where to locate image files get pulled from `docker pull hello-world` etc. and how to change location of these folders ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running docker on windows using docker toolbox the directory 
/var/lib/docker refers to your virtual machine (boot2Docker).Connect to the machine:

```
docker-machine ssh <machine>
```

and type:

```
sudo ls /var/lib/docker
```

to see the content.

You can change Docker's storage base directory (where container and images go) using the -g option when starting the Docker daemon.

Edit the file profile:

```
sudo vi /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
```

and add the -g option to the EXTRA_ARGS variable:

```
EXTRA_ARGS='
--label provider=virtualbox
-g <path>
'
```

save and restart the machine:

```
docker-machine restart <machine>
```

connect againt to your machine using ssh and verify the changes typing:

```
docker info
```

Hope this can help.